# How to make a child view not clickable inside a clickable container

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have a layout container like described below:

```
<ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
...>
   <child1/>
   <child2/>
   <child3/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

In my code, I have to attach a click listener to the container to be able to execute an action when the user clicks on any area of the container.
What is the best solution to exclude the child2 from this constraint? I mean, all the container areas should be clickable but the child2 shouldn't.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the following and it worked, just a workaround and it may not be the optimal solution

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/container"
android:onClick = "doSomething"
...>
   <child1/>
   <child2
   android:onClick="doNothing"/>
   <child3/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

**Activity** class

```
//all but child2 responds to the clickevent
    fun doNothing(view: View) {
        //does nothing,empty function
    }

    fun doSomething(view: View) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "did something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any optimal solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

for children. Then they won't react on clicks.